# Viewing the world seed in the multiplayer mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I get a seed of the world in the multiplayer mode in Minecraft, if I'm the owner? I'm currently on Minecraft 1.2.5

Comment: This was purposely disabled in the latest version, officially at least.

Comment: I've heard that it was made for not alowing players to cheat or something. But if I own a server and want to know a seed of the generated world, what can I do in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find out the seed for my multiplayer world by downloading [this program](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/626786-v2031-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-ect-finder/) and opening the level.dat, with the program, in the world folder for the world that you are running. When you do that, it will display the seed in the top-left corner of the program. To make sure that it is the correct seed, simply make a new singleplayer world with that seed and check the coordinates by pressing F3. You can then go to your multiplayer world, to see if the world looks the same by going to the coordinates that you checked in your singleplayer world.

Comment: What if your a player and want the seed of a multiplayer world so that you can search for a spawner or such in creative mode? I know that since they disabled the seed in the f3 menu you can't see it, but I found a program that let you enter the coordinates of slime chunks and once you had enough coordinates entered, it could tell you how many seeds had slime chunks in those spots. Unfortunately there are no slime chunks in 1.4, so does anyone have any other brilliant ideas to find the seed?

Comment: @WIking This question is about finding the seed when you are the server operator. If you want to ask a *different* question: [Ask].

Answer (score 3):

Enter the `/seed` command in chat and the seed will be displayed. In vanilla servers, operator access is required to use this command.

Comment: Hi, yoshy, and welcome to Arqade!  While technically correct, this answer isn't very descriptive.  Can you please expand and improve on it?  In the future, try and give answers that include all the necessary details.

Comment: This answer seems perfectly clear to me. I had the same question as the OP, and this answered it.